# Какой класс самый базовый для рисования?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Какой класс в WPF самый базовый и "низкоуровневый" для рисования (все равно чего)? Я так понимаю это класс Pen, Point итп. Сорри, если неправильно поставил вопрос. Всего лишь любитель C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, именно `Pen` для рисования линий, структурирования фигур или визуализации других геометрических представлений.